# "Consumer Closed" when acknowledging message with JmsTemplate receive method

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have an activemq queue where messages are being sent to and the application uses Spring JmsTemplate `receiveSelected(selector)` to receive the messages synchronously. Message is processed before it is acknowledged. If the broker or the application shuts down before acknowledging the message while it is being processed the message needs to be resent or redelivered without getting lost. My understanding is with client_acknowledgement messages gets resent if not acknowledged also.

Configuration

```xml
<bean id="jmsConnection" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="broker" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
</bean>
```

Redelivery Policy:

```xml
<bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="2" />
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="5" />
</bean>
```

JmsTemplate:

```xml
<bean id="jmstemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnection" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="messageQueue"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Session call back to receive message:

```java
Object getProcessedMessageObject {
   return jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
      @Override
      public Object doInJms (Session session) throws JMSException {
         Object tmp = null;
         MapMessage msg = (MapMessage) jmsTemplate.receiveSelected(selector);
         try {
            if (msg != null) {
               MapMessage receivedMsg = msg;
               tmp = processMsg(receivedMsg) if (tmp != null) {
                  msg.acknowledge();
               }
            }
         } catch (JMSException) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
         } return tmp;
      }
   });
}
```

I am getting "Consumer is closed" when `msg.acknowledge()` is called. When I stop and restart my application the messages are not redelivered as they are not acknowledged. I'm trying to understand what I am missing and how to make it work.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `<property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>`?

Comment: @DougGrove Removing that property did not help. I found that the message was getting acknowledged when it was sent to processMsg(). That fixed it. Now my message is not getting redelivered if there is an exception from the application.  I added session.recover() before throwing runtime exception.

Comment: I thought that your message was getting delivered and acknowledged.  I couldn't remember if setting `sessionTransacted` after setting `sessionAcknowledgeMode` actually overrode the `sessionAcknowledgeMode`.

Comment: Settingg sessionAcknowledgeMode to ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE, sessiongTransacted to false and adding session.recover() before throwing exception redelivered the messages.